# CSS Positioning Inside Navigation Bar

Tags: css, css-position

I am learning how to make a responsive website following a [tutorial here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) -- this is my [demo project](http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/index.html)) but I am having a problem: I cannot position anything to the right of the `<ul>` inside the `<nav>`. For some reason everything (including the `#pull` link when the display is not set to "none") falls below the `<nav>` and the `<ul>`. I want to make a login form somewhere to the right of the `<ul>` in the `<nav>` and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it at all.

Im sure its just a basic CSS positioning issue that I can't figure out because I am new to this, but I just need to place more content on the `<nav>` and I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: Could you please include your `html`/`css` or a working http://www.jsfiddle.net? Also is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/symzZ/

Comment: Can you put this into a http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can play with the code a bit and then post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

The widht's limit it's the problem: see the class `nav ul` has `width: 600px;` you need rework the width size for `nav ul` in all stylesheet.

Example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/itz8j1aeyyyufbh/Screenshot%202014-01-02%2020.10.07.png

```
nav ul {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `display` property, for default is `block` on `ul` elements, with that property you can't position elements right aside. Try this:

```
nav ul, nav > a#pull {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And to keep the horizontal align this:

```
nav {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats perfect...I did that but changed it just a bit I went

Comment: nav ul{
display:inline-block;
}

nav > a#pull{
display:inline-block;
float:right;
}

Now its on the same line as the <ul> in the <nav> bar, but floats to the right so its separated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything falls below the title because your ul has an automatic margin on the sides. If you wanted to put your pull link on the right and you  do not mind using absolute positioning you could do something like this:

```
#pull {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```