# Can't Center Responsive Navigation Bar Elements?

Tags: html, navigation, css-position, css

I am learning how to make a responsive website following a tutorial here http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/

I am having a problem: I cannot position anything to the right of the `<ul>` inside the `<nav>`. For some reason everything (including the `#pull` link) falls below the `<nav>` and the `<ul>`, or if I position it next to it, the `<ul>` isn't centered in the `<nav>`, which takes up 100% of the screen width. I want to make a login form somewhere to the right of the `<ul>` in the `<nav>` and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it at all.

I'm sure its just a basic CSS positioning issue that I can't figure out because I am new to this, but I just need to place more content on the `<nav>` and I cannot figure out how to.

ALSO: This is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HRo77RSb3FZnowbTc2RGJiRGs/edit?usp=sharing

With the code that is currently on the file above, the link will sit underneath the navigation bar, if in the html code, you pull the `<div>` and `<a>` back into the `<nav>` it will sit in the navigation bar, but push everything to the left. I need it to be inside the navigation bar with the `<ul>` still centered in the entire screen.

Comment: This question made little sense since all the HTML elements were not escaped with backticks, and so were invisible. I've fixed them all, but please do read the formatting guidelines, and use the question previewer, prior to posting a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Positioning Inside Navigation Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889805/css-positioning-inside-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what 'the' means, for example:

> I cannot position anything to the right of the inside the .

Also, I can't open the link you put, it's basically showing nothing, am I the only one?

But I'll try anyway.

> With the code that is currently on the file above, the link will sit
>   underneath the navigation bar

Did you make sure you use

```
float: left;
```

I sadly can't help you more because you provided very little information.